# How can I fix Emacs' syntax highlighting of qr"\.[^.]+$"?

Tags: regex, perl, emacs, syntax-highlighting

Emacs is confusing syntax after a line like

```
fileparse($file, qr"\.[^.]+$");
```

And thinks the rest of the file is a string. How do I fix this?

Comment: It is not because of Perl regexes but due to your choice of pattern markers. Just stick with the standard `/` unless your pattern has `/` in it if you want your code to be easily readable by others. "Doctor, it hurts when I bend my arm backwards like this." "Well, don't bend your arm that way then!"

Comment: Are you using `cperl-mode` (if not you should be)?  It doesn't get confused for me on Emacs 24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs is confused by the quotes in the `qr` expression. The standard regular expression delimiter (/) works:

```
fileparse($file, qr/\.[^.]+$/);
```

In fact, almost anything else seems to work.

```
fileparse($file, qr{(\.[^.]+$/});
fileparse($file, qr*\.[^.]+$*);
fileparse($file, qr#\.[^.]+$#);
```

My version of VIM doesn't get confused by the quotes, but I know that older versions of VIM did. Putting quotes is really confusing because it makes the `qr` expression look like a string (which it isn't). It's usually bad policy to use quotes as delimiters in regular expressions even though it's technically legal.

However, the really important question is what's `fileparse`? That's not a standard Perl function. I am assuming that this is imported from `File::Basename`? Would that be correct?

According to the documentation I have, the second argument in `fileparse` is suppose to be an array and not a quoted regular expression.

Comment: *If `@suffixes` are given each element is a pattern (either a string or a `qr//`) matched against the end of the `$filename`.* So, the OP has a list of suffixes that consists of a single element. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: How does emacs do using `'` as delimiter? that is one that gets used for preventing interpolation. I can't check because Emacs scares the bejesus out of me :-P

Answer (score 3):

David W. probably has the right answer. Again, probably best to avoid using `"` as delimiter, but sometimes you need to use `'` as the delimiter to prevent interpolation, therefore this may be useful to someone in that case.

So, if for some reason you REALLY want the quote delimiter (or to prevent interpolation using `'`), you can always do something like:

```
fileparse($file, qr"\.[^.]+$"); #"# highlight fix
```

an example using one that SO does badly:

```
s'hi'by'; #'# highlight fix
```

note: the second `#` is to trigger the comment highlighting in the editor so that `highlight fix` shows as a comment.